# enable full screen mode in android app

Tags: android, fullscreen

I know this has been asked before, in fact Ive been googling it for days, but I cant get my app to go full screen in android api 19 os version 4.2.1

Ive tried

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and also

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
                    .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

but neither of these work. I also tried choosing a full screen theme in the manifest file but this didnt work. What could be wrong?

Comment: Could you maybe explain what isn't working? Does the status bar still show? The toolbar? And/Or the navigation bar?

Comment: Immersive mode was added in API Level 19 which is Android 4.4, not 4.2.1.

Comment: The system bar still shows on the bottom, the one with battery life and the back and home buttons

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're calling your code before you call your `setContentView();` Otherwise, it won't have any affect. Something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```